# Clarification/Musing on Python Lambda function in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, lambda

I'm finally breaking free from the shackles of SPSS and am reveling in the freedom of Pandas and Python (love it). However, I'm trying to get a clearer picture of how the python Lambda function interacts in Pandas. It seems to pop up a lot. Here is an example I hope will clear up the murkiness.

After creating a new dataframe from a string split:

```
 bs = fh['basis'].str.split(',',expand = True)
```

I want to rename all the variables by adding a "b" to the numeric headers. This works:

```
 n = list(bs)
 for x in n:
     bs.rename(columns={x : 'b' + str(x)},inplace = True)
```

But I have a sneaking suspicion a lambda function would be better. However, this doesn't work:

```
 bs.rename(columns=lambda x: x = 'b' + str(x), inplace=True)
```

I thought lambda acted as a function, so if I pass in a column header I can append a 'b' to it. But the "=" throws an error. Any quick observations would be much appreciated. 
Cheers!

Comment: You could have just done `bs.columns = 'b' + bs.columns.astype(str)`

Comment: Oh that's a nice solution too. I didn't know you could access all columns like that.  Super helpful - thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd use [add_prefix()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.add_prefix.html):

```
In [5]: bs = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(3,5))

In [6]: bs
Out[6]:
          0         1         2         3         4
0  0.521593  0.088293  0.623103  0.099417  0.983149
1  0.009741  0.465654  0.414261  0.024086  0.039543
2  0.476219  0.918162  0.900815  0.126549  0.112388

In [7]: bs.add_prefix('b')
Out[7]:
         b0        b1        b2        b3        b4
0  0.521593  0.088293  0.623103  0.099417  0.983149
1  0.009741  0.465654  0.414261  0.024086  0.039543
2  0.476219  0.918162  0.900815  0.126549  0.112388
```

Answer (score 5):

You could've done this even easier by just adding the columns to `'b'` after casting to `str` using `astype`:

```
In [2]:
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=np.arange(5))
df

Out[2]:
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
Index: []

In [4]:
df.columns = 'b' + df.columns.astype(str)
df.columns

Out[4]:
Index(['b0', 'b1', 'b2', 'b3', 'b4'], dtype='object')
```

Answer (score 1):

Ahhhh! Of course I figured it out beofre I could even submit it.

```
 bs.rename(columns=lambda x: 'b' + str(x), inplace=True)
```

Is of course the answer. The equals sign is redundant, whatever after the ":" is what the function will return or "equal". Is that correct idea?

Comment: That is correct. But there is a better option for this particular example: `bs.add_prefix('b')` ;-)

Comment: @MaxU never encountered that method before